# What are the requirements for physically securing exterior coax and cat6 to a house or outside dwelling?

Tags: data-wiring, coaxial-cable

I assume that there are some. Like a bracket every X inches or something but I can't find any.
Hillsborough County, Florida if it matters.

I find lots of articles talking about how the right kind of cable is important (vs cable rated for interior) and there is plenty of documentation of how far you can run the cable but I can't find any codes regarding how frequently you need to secure it to a wall or something else.

I'm sure I'm, just using the wrong keywords or something but I can find plenty of info about how electrical wire needs support every X inches depending on if if it NM or not but nothing about data.

Comment: Most data cables won't burn down a house or shock you into next week, so they don't get as much loving.  Basically mount them so they look nice and don't clothesline a bike rider.

Comment: Seems like an answer, @crip659.

Comment: That's what I thought too but I got a letter from my insurance company saying that I need to pay an electrician to sign off on if they are installed correctly. And, well, I can't find that there is anything to state that there is an incorrect way to install them.

Comment: Would imagine an electrician knows as much about as you do.  It is not his job.  This is something a cable or telephone installer would know.

Comment: Call insurance and tell them you called an electrician and he said that this is not electrical and he cannot sign off on something that isn't referred to in code.   That's how I would handle it.   You would be the 1 billionth person that an insurance company tried to get something signed off on that makes no sense.

Comment: Did letter mention any specific electrician/s, if so this beginning to sound like a scam.  Would call insurance just to double check.

Comment: If your insurance company continues to push for _some_ kind of sign-off, consider getting a note from the City/County inspector saying they've reviewed and are satisfied. Frankly, that would carry more weight than an electrician's note anyway - the inspector has final say over what the electrician does in the long run.

Comment: Sounds like your insurance company did an inspection and they needed to find something to make it look like the inspector did his job. Now they want a letter so send them a letter. In the letter tell them you contacted an electrician and the city inspector and they stated "there's no standard in the code, just needs to be safely secured,  it carries no voltage, etc. or something to that effect". Attach some before and after pictures.  Or spend a whole bunch of time on the phone with the person that just needs a letter for his file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no code requirements for catX or coax on how they are secured.

Now dealing with some pretty finicky city inspectors...  I will say that they want them tight to house or whatever they are running on and using a good clamp.   They generally don't care how many unless they are so spread out that it looks too loose (what's too loose?... who knows?... what's a workman-like manner?).

These are the clips that I use for both -

[image]

These come in a variety of colors, pick one that keeps them hidden and for sure get the screws so you can adjust them easy.   *(I also like these because I use a hex adapter on my screwdriver not phillips.  Its much faster, doesn't strip the screws and best of all when the screw is completely out it is easier to balance screwing in thing above.  I never even try to screw these in using the phillips adapter anymore)*

Now other than making your inspector happy the only thing I have ever heard or had mentioned to me in years of renovating older houses is nothing along the ground (bury it) and no runs horizontal below 8' (and was told 10' once).   This keeps it from clotheslining someone.

If you are overly concerned call up your city inspector.   I am 99% sure he will just mention workmanlike manner, tight/neat, and nothing to trip or clothesline... but he can also say whatever he wants as he calls the shots.   He could be well if it is clipped on metal I require these clips and so on... not saying that would happen but it does happen for a variety of things that are not covered in building code or NEC guides.

Note: you can put both in these brackets.   I haven't done that outside but I have many times ran cat6 and coax on basement ceilings together using these clips.   The coax keeps the cat6 tighter.

Comment: That's what I thought but I got a letter from my insurance company saying that I need to pay an electrician to sign off on if they are installed correctly. And, well, I can't find that there is anything to state that there is an incorrect way to install them. So I'll try calling them and ask for them to provide the code that I am violating I guess since I can't prove a negative. Thanks

Comment: That's really odd - why does your insurance company even know?    These types of cables are so far outside the realm of insurance that seems odd.   Also you might never get an inspector to even look at your house as far as these cables are concerned unless you are having other stuff done.   No inspector ever came out to inspect my cables... they just said stuff when inspecting roof/siding/whatever.   Comcast installers don't have inspectors following them around... although maybe they should.

Comment: There are code requirtements for SELV,  basically they say don't get too close to power wires.  There are also other building codes eg: don't build a trip hazard or obstruct an emergency exit...

Comment: @DMoore - I'm in florida and it is hurricane season. If I had to bet, they have contractors driving around looking for things to justify dropping wind coverage. Part of the letter also says we need to clean up the driveway. When I called they explained that we can't have anything in our yard or driveway except the cars and garbage cans. So yeah... looking for a new insurance company but can't lose coverage during storm season either and that isn't a great time to look for one if I want good prices.

Answer (score 3):

### Just make sure that the cable can't get snagged/damaged

The governing criterion for data cable securement is in NEC 800.24, and simply requires you to secure the cable so it can't get damaged during the normal use of the building:

> Cables installed exposed on the surface of
> ceilings and sidewalls shall be supported by the building structure in such a manner that the cable will not be damaged by
> normal building use. Such cables shall be secured by hardware,
> including straps, staples, cable ties, hangers, or similar fittings,
> designed and installed so as not to damage the cable. The
> installation shall also conform to 300.4(D) and 300.11.

Answer (score 3):

You could say 5 feet / 1.5 meters, but that's a conflation of ANSI/TIA-569-B-2004, "Commercial Building Standard for Telecommunications Pathways and Spaces" which really can't be said to actually apply to cables on the outside of a private residence. It's **A** standard, it's **not code**, and it's not an **applicable** standard for the location and occupancy...

I'd say your insurance company is just jerking you around and you should be shopping for a different insurance company.